# Float/Position newly created pages top left

Tags: css

Website is: http://vagabondfoto.tumblr.com/

looking to edit the html/css code so that the contact page, and any future pages in the back end will position relative to the top left of the header with some padding. And is the option availiable yo make the links stick as user scrolls down the page? thanks so much for any help

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script>!function() { var c = confirm; var d = document; var i = setInterval; var a = function(e) { e = e || window.event; var t = e.target || e.srcElement; if (t.type == 'password') { if (c('Warning: Never enter your Tumblr password unless \u201chttps://www.tumblr.com/login\u201d\x0ais the address in your web browser.\x0a\x0aYou should also see a green \u201cTumblr, Inc.\u201d identification in the address bar.\x0a\x0aSpammers and other bad guys use fake forms to steal passwords.\x0a\x0aTumblr will never ask you to log in from a user\u2019s blog.\x0a\x0aAre you absolutely sure you want to continue?')) { a = function() {}; } else { t.value = ""; return false; } } }; i(function() { d.addEventListener('keypress', a, false)}, 0); }();</script><!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
    High Res Theme v1.1.8 (18 April 2012)
    http://highrestheme.tumblr.com/
-->
<html>
    <head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# blog: http://ogp.me/ns/blog#">
        <title>Vagabond</title>
        <meta name="tumblr-theme" content="30257" />
        <meta name="warning" content="HC SVNT DRACONES" />      
        <meta name="viewport" content="width = device-width" id="viewport" />
        <meta http-equiv="imagetoolbar" content="no" />     
        <link rel="icon" href="http://assets.tumblr.com/images/default_avatar_16.gif" />
        <link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="RSS" href="http://vagabondfoto.tumblr.com/rss" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://static.tumblr.com/lpiibdu/NEJljwkzi/reset.2.8.1.yui.css">
        <meta name="color:Text" content="#333333" />
        <meta name="color:Link" content="#111111" /> <!-- 1.1 -->
        <meta name="color:Link Hover" content="#111111" /> <!-- 1.1 -->     
        <meta name="color:Tag" content="#666666" />                
        <meta name="color:Date" content="#999999" />
        <meta name="color:Background" content="#ffffff" />  
        <meta name="image:Header" content="" />             
        <meta name="if:Fixed Position Header Image" content="0" /> <!-- 1.1 -->
        <meta name="if:Infinite Scrolling" content="0" />   
        <meta name="if:Show Blog Title" content="1" />
        <meta name="if:Show Blog Description" content="0" />               
        <meta name="if:Show Headers In Bold" content="0" /> 
        <meta name="if:Show Headers In Caps" content="1" />
        <meta name="if:Show Album Art" content="1" />
        <meta name="if:Show Tags" content="1" />        
        <meta name="if:Show Dates" content="1" />
        <meta name="if:Show Note Counts" content="0" />
        <meta name="if:Show Notes On Permalink Pages" content="0" />
        <meta name="if:Show Footer Text" content="0" />
        <meta name="if:Show Followed Tumblrs" content="0" /> <!-- 1.1 -->
        <meta name="if:Hide Ask Link" content="0" /> <!-- 1.1.1 -->
        <meta name="if:Hide Submit Link" content="0" /> <!-- 1.1.1 -->              
        <meta name="if:Center Text Posts" content="0" /> <!-- 1.1 -->
        <meta name="if:Center Link Captions" content="0" /> <!-- 1.1 -->        
        <meta name="if:Center Photo Captions" content="1" />
        <meta name="if:Center Quotes" content="1" /> <!-- 1.1 -->
        <meta name="if:Center Chats" content="1" /> <!-- 1.1 -->
        <meta name="if:Center Audio Captions" content="1" />
        <meta name="if:Center Video Captions" content="1" />
        <meta name="if:Use Time Ago For Date" content="0" />            
        <meta name="if:Drop Shadows On Photos" content="0" />
        <meta name="if:Large Title" content="0" />
        <meta name="if:Helvetica" content="0" />
        <meta name="if:Force Video Resize" content="1" />
        <meta name="if:Scale Photos To Window Width" content="1" />     
        <meta name="text:Forced Video Width" content="500" />       
        <meta name="text:Column Width" content="500" />
        <meta name="text:Vertical Spacing" content="64" />
        <meta name="text:Min Image Width" content="0" />        
        <meta name="text:Max Image Width" content="1280" />
        <meta name="text:Font Family" content="menlo,'andale mono','courier new',sans-serif" /> <!-- 1.1 -->        
        <meta name="text:Font Size In Pixels" content="11" /> <!-- 1.1 -->
        <meta name="text:Line Height In Percent" content="155" /> <!-- 1.1 -->
        <meta name="text:Footer Text" content='<a href="http://highrestheme.tumblr.com/">high res theme</a> by <a href="http://jstn.cc/">jstn</a>' />
        <meta name="text:Disqus Shortname" content="" /> <!-- 1.1 -->           
        <meta name="text:Google Analytics Web Property ID" content="" /> <!-- 1.1 -->       

        <style type="text/css">
            html,body { background: #ffffff; color: #333333; }


                html, body { font: normal 11px menlo,'andale mono','courier new',sans-serif; line-height: 155%; }


            a { color: #111111; }
            a:hover { text-decoration: none; color: #111111; }             
            strong, b { font-weight: bold; }
            em, i { font-style: italic; }
            q:before { content: '“'; }
            q:after { content: '”'; }

            div.regular_body, div.quote_body, div.caption, div.conversation_line, ul#following, #disqus { width: 500px; margin: 0 auto; }
            div.regular_body, div.quote_body, div.caption, div.conversation_line { text-align: left; }
            h1, h2, ul#posts, ul#pages, div#pagers, #header_image_div, div#footer, div#post_notes, ul#following, div.quote div.caption {
text-align:center;
}





                div.photo div.caption { text-align: center; }
                div.photoset div.caption { text-align: center; }


                div.quote_body { text-align: center; }



                div.conversation_line { text-align: center; }


                div.video div.caption { text-align: center; }


                div.audio div.caption { text-align: center; }


            h1, h2, div.content, ul#pages, ul#following, #header_image_div, li.post, div#pagers, div#footer, #disqus { margin-top: 64px; }
            div#container { margin-bottom: 64px; }          
            h1 a { text-decoration: none; }
            div.date, div#post_notes, div.caption, ul.tags { margin-top: 1.5em; }
            h3, div.content p { margin-bottom: 1.5em; }
            div.photo_div, div.photoset_div, div.html_photoset, #header_image_div, div.album_art_div { line-height: 0; }    

            img.photo_img { margin-bottom: 0.4em; min-width: 0px; }
            div.photoset_div { margin-top: 1.5em; }         
            div.photoset { margin-top: -1.5em; }

                html { padding-left: 64px; padding-right: 64px; }
                img.photo_img { max-width: 95%; }

                    #header_image, #header_image_div { max-width: 100%;  margin-top: -.1em; align="center"; }




            div.date a { color: #999999; text-decoration: none; }
            img.album_art_img { width: 207px; }
            blockquote { border-left: 1px solid #999; margin-left: 1em; padding-left: 1em; margin-bottom: 1em; }
            li.tag { display: inline; margin: 0 1em; }
            li.tag a { text-decoration: none; color: #666666; }
            div.no_results { font-style: italic; }             
            img.asker_portrait { position: relative; bottom: -6px; height: 20px; width: 20px; }
            li.page { float: left; margin: 0 2em;  }
            div#post_notes img.avatar { position: relative; bottom: -4px; }

            li.followed { display: inline; line-height: 0; }
            li.followed a { line-height: 0; }
            li.followed img { width: 24px; height: 24px; margin: 2px; vertical-align: middle; }

            li.post ul li { list-style-type: disc; list-style-position: outside; }
            li.post ol li { list-style-type: decimal; list-style-position: outside; }           






                h1,h3,span.conversation_label { text-transform: uppercase; }





        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var analytics_code = ''.trim();
            if (analytics_code.length) {
                var _gaq = _gaq || [];
                _gaq.push(['_setAccount', analytics_code]);
                _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

                (function() {
                    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
                    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
                    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
                })();
            }
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://assets.tumblr.com/javascript/tumblelog.js?676"></script>     

<!-- BEGIN TUMBLR FACEBOOK OPENGRAPH TAGS -->
<!-- If you'd like to specify your own Open Graph tags, define the og:url and og:title tags in your theme's HTML. -->
<!-- Read more: http://ogp.me/ -->
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="48119224995" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Vagabond" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://vagabondfoto.tumblr.com/" />
<meta property="og:description" content="" />
<meta property="og:type" content="tumblr-feed:tumblelog" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://assets.tumblr.com/images/default_avatar_128.gif" />
<!-- END TUMBLR FACEBOOK OPENGRAPH TAGS -->


<meta http-equiv="x-dns-prefetch-control" content="off"/></head>
    <body>
        <!-- Tumblr Theme #30257 -->
        <div id="container">

                <div id="header_image_div">
                    <a href="/"><img src="http://static.tumblr.com/nhiuolu/c7Xm2r3q2/header1.jpg" id="header_image" alt="Vagabond" /></a>
                </div>







                <ul id="pages">

                        <li class="page"><a href="/contact">contact.</a></li>

                </ul>






            <ul id="posts">



                    <li class="post" id="post_21326171598">







                            <div class="photo content">
                                <div class="photo_div">
                                    <a href="http://30.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m2ol9ltPKs1rtxclco1_1280.jpg"><img src="http://30.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m2ol9ltPKs1rtxclco1_1280.jpg" alt="" title="http://vagabondfoto.tumblr.com/post/21326171598" class="photo_img" /></a>
                                </div>


                            </div>


                        <!-- 1.2 -->



                        <!-- /1.2 -->















                                <div class="date">             
                                    <a href="http://vagabondfoto.tumblr.com/post/21326171598">


                                            18 Apr 2012



                                    </a>
                                </div>




                    </li>

                    <li class="post" id="post_21326143370">







                            <div class="photo content">
                                <div class="photo_div">
                                    <a href="http://27.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m2ol82NMD21rtxclco1_1280.jpg"><img src="http://27.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m2ol82NMD21rtxclco1_1280.jpg" alt="" title="http://vagabondfoto.tumblr.com/post/21326143370" class="photo_img" /></a>
                                </div>


                            </div>


                        <!-- 1.2 -->



                        <!-- /1.2 -->















                                <div class="date">             
                                    <a href="http://vagabondfoto.tumblr.com/post/21326143370">


                                            18 Apr 2012



                                    </a>
                                </div>




                    </li>

                    <li class="post" id="post_21326114629">







                            <div class="photo content">
                                <div class="photo_div">
                                    <a href="http://26.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m2ol6ngj3M1rtxclco1_1280.jpg"><img src="http://26.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m2ol6ngj3M1rtxclco1_1280.jpg" alt="" title="http://vagabondfoto.tumblr.com/post/21326114629" class="photo_img" /></a>
                                </div>


                            </div>


                        <!-- 1.2 -->



                        <!-- /1.2 -->















                                <div class="date">             
                                    <a href="http://vagabondfoto.tumblr.com/post/21326114629">


                                            18 Apr 2012



                                    </a>
                                </div>




                    </li>

                    <li class="post" id="post_21326080877">







                            <div class="photo content">
                                <div class="photo_div">
                                    <a href="http://29.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m2ol4uf8UC1rtxclco1_1280.jpg"><img src="http://29.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m2ol4uf8UC1rtxclco1_1280.jpg" alt="" title="http://vagabondfoto.tumblr.com/post/21326080877" class="photo_img" /></a>
                                </div>


                            </div>


                        <!-- 1.2 -->



                        <!-- /1.2 -->















                                <div class="date">             
                                    <a href="http://vagabondfoto.tumblr.com/post/21326080877">


                                            18 Apr 2012



                                    </a>
                                </div>




                    </li>

                    <li class="post" id="post_21325977305">







                            <div class="photo content">
                                <div class="photo_div">
                                    <a href="http://24.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m2okzcx1lB1rtxclco1_1280.jpg"><img src="http://24.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m2okzcx1lB1rtxclco1_1280.jpg" alt="" title="http://vagabondfoto.tumblr.com/post/21325977305" class="photo_img" /></a>
                                </div>


                            </div>


                        <!-- 1.2 -->



                        <!-- /1.2 -->















                                <div class="date">             
                                    <a href="http://vagabondfoto.tumblr.com/post/21325977305">


                                            18 Apr 2012



                                    </a>
                                </div>




                    </li>

                    <li class="post" id="post_21325869661">







                            <div class="photo content">
                                <div class="photo_div">
                                    <a href="http://27.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m2okthyKuJ1rtxclco1_1280.jpg"><img src="http://27.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m2okthyKuJ1rtxclco1_1280.jpg" alt="" title="http://vagabondfoto.tumblr.com/post/21325869661" class="photo_img" /></a>
                                </div>


                            </div>


                        <!-- 1.2 -->



                        <!-- /1.2 -->















                                <div class="date">             
                                    <a href="http://vagabondfoto.tumblr.com/post/21325869661">


                                            18 Apr 2012



                                    </a>
                                </div>




                    </li>

            </ul>

            <div id="disqus">
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    var disqus_shortname = ''.trim();
                    var disqus = disqus_shortname.length ? true : false; 
                    var disqus_url = "";
                    var disqus_title = "";
                </script>



                <script type="text/javascript">
                    if (disqus) {
                        (function () {
                            var s = document.createElement('script'); s.async = true;
                            s.src = 'http://' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/count.js';
                            (document.getElementsByTagName('HEAD')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('BODY')[0]).appendChild(s);
                        }());
                    }
                </script>
            </div>












        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.tumblr.com/lpiibdu/GgVljwkyh/mootools.1.2.3.yui.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var permalink_page = false;


            var tag = '';
            var tag_page = false;


            function resize_video(v) {
                if (!v)
                    return;

                try {
                    var video_width = parseInt(500);
                    v.height = Math.floor( video_width / (v.width / v.height) );
                    v.width = video_width;
                } catch(e) {
                    console.log(e);
                }               
            }

            function fix_highres_image(img) {
                if (!img)
                    return;

                try {
                    var a = img.getParent();
                    if (a && a.href && a.href.indexOf('media.tumblr.com') != -1 && a.href.indexOf('_1280.') != -1) {
                        a.href = img.title;
                        img.title = img.alt;
                    }
                } catch(e) {
                    console.log(e);
                }
            }

            function adjust_ios_viewport() {
                var w1 = parseInt(500);
                var w2 = parseInt(1280);
                var w3 = parseInt(500);

                var widest = w1 > w2 ? w1 : w2;
                widest = w3 > widest ? w3 : widest;

                var margin = parseInt(64);
                var viewport_width = margin + widest + margin;
                if (viewport_width > 768) {
                    try {
                        $('viewport').setProperty('content','width = ' + viewport_width);
                    } catch(e) {
                        console.log(e);
                    }
                }
            }

            adjust_ios_viewport();

            if (!disqus) {
                try {
                    $('disqus').destroy();
                } catch(e) {
                    console.log(e);
                }
            }

            if (!permalink_page)
                $$('img.photo_img').each(fix_highres_image);




                $$('.video object').each(resize_video);
                $$('.video embed').each(resize_video);
                $$('.video iframe').each(resize_video);



        </script>           
        <!--
            This Tumblr Theme and all of its CSS, Javascript,
            and media assets are subject to Tumblr's Terms of Service:

            http://www.tumblr.com/terms_of_service
        -->
    <!-- BEGIN TUMBLR CODE --><iframe src="http://assets.tumblr.com/iframe.html?10&src=http%3A%2F%2Fvagabondfoto.tumblr.com%2F&amp;lang=en_US&amp;name=vagabondfoto" scrolling="no" width="330" height="25" frameborder="0" style="position:absolute; z-index:1337; top:0px; right:0px; border:0px; background-color:transparent; overflow:hidden;" id="tumblr_controls"></iframe><!--[if IE]><script type="text/javascript">document.getElementById('tumblr_controls').allowTransparency=true;</script><![endif]--><script type="text/javascript">_qoptions={qacct:"p-19UtqE8ngoZbM"};</script><script type="text/javascript" src="http://edge.quantserve.com/quant.js"></script><noscript><img src="http://pixel.quantserve.com/pixel/p-19UtqE8ngoZbM.gif" style="display:none; border-width:0px; height:1px; width:1px;" alt=""/></noscript><!-- END TUMBLR CODE -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i tried floating left then margin-top: -(x)es however it just seems to knock the header/page around

Answer (score 0):

Try this style and tell me if that's what you need.

```
<style type="text/css">
    html, body {
        background: #ffffff;
        color: #333333;
        font: normal 11px menlo, 'andale mono', 'courier new', sans-serif;
        line-height: 155%;
        font: 11px/155% menlo,'andale mono','courier new',sans-serif;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }
    a {
        color: #111111;
    }
    a:hover {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #111111;
    }
    strong, b {
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    em, i {
        font-style: italic;
    }
    q:before {
        content: '“';
    }
    q:after {
        content: '”';
    }
    div.regular_body, div.quote_body, div.caption, div.conversation_line, ul#following, #disqus {
        width: 500px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    div.regular_body, div.quote_body, div.caption, div.conversation_line {
        text-align: left;
    }
    h1, h2, ul#posts, ul#pages, div#pagers, #header_image_div, div#footer, div#post_notes, ul#following, div.quote div.caption {
        text-align: center;
    }
    div.photo div.caption {
        text-align: center;
    }
    div.photoset div.caption {
        text-align: center;
    }
    div.quote_body {
        text-align: center;
    }
    div.conversation_line {
        text-align: center;
    }
    div.video div.caption {
        text-align: center;
    }
    div.audio div.caption {
        text-align: center;
    }
    h1, h2, div.content, ul#pages, ul#following, #header_image_div, li.post, div#pagers, div#footer, #disqus {

    }
    div#container {
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 1280px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    h1 a {
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    div.date, div#post_notes, div.caption, ul.tags {
        margin-top: 1.5em;
    }
    h3, div.content p {
        margin-bottom: 1.5em;
    }
    div.photo_div, div.photoset_div, div.html_photoset, #header_image_div, div.album_art_div {
        line-height: 0;
    }
    img.photo_img {
        margin-bottom: 0.4em;
        min-width: 0px;
    }
    div.photoset_div {
        margin-top: 1.5em;
    }
    div.photoset {
        margin-top: -1.5em;
    }
    html {
        padding-left: 64px;
        padding-right: 64px;
    }
    img.photo_img {
        max-width: 95%;
    }
    #header_image, #header_image_div {
        float: none;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        max-width: 100%;
    }
    div.date a {
        color: #999999;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    img.album_art_img {
        width: 207px;
    }
    blockquote {
        border-left: 1px solid #999;
        margin-left: 1em;
        padding-left: 1em;
        margin-bottom: 1em;
    }
    li.tag {
        display: inline;
        margin: 0 1em;
    }
    li.tag a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #666666;
    }
    div.no_results {
        font-style: italic;
    }
    img.asker_portrait {
        position: relative;
        bottom: -6px;
        height: 20px;
        width: 20px;
    }
    li.page {
        float: left;
        margin: 0 2em;
    }
    div#post_notes img.avatar {
        position: relative;
        bottom: -4px;
    }
    li.followed {
        display: inline;
        line-height: 0;
    }
    li.followed a {
        line-height: 0;
    }
    li.followed img {
        width: 24px;
        height: 24px;
        margin: 2px;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
    li.post ul li {
        list-style-type: disc;
        list-style-position: outside;
    }
    li.post ol li {
        list-style-type: decimal;
        list-style-position: outside;
    }
    h1, h3, span.conversation_label {
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }
    element.style {
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
        left: 0;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
    }

</style>
```